# Как обрезать url, чтобы получить строку без слеш в php?

Tags: php

Как обрезать url, чтобы получить строку без слеш в php? Я хочу получить из этого url https://mbb.starcev.agency/collections/dream/     строку dream. Буду рад любой помощи!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что у вас там: обрезать или получить строку dream.

**Обрезать:**

```
print(substr("https://mbb.starcev.agency/collections/dream/", 0, -1));
```

Вывод: `https://mbb.starcev.agency/collections/dream`

**Получить dream:**

```
print(explode('/', parse_url('https://mbb.starcev.agency/collections/dream/', PHP_URL_PATH))[2]);
```

Вывод: `dream`